# Why is joining the channel failing in test network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to edit the test network script and I'm getting this error:

> Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded

I have confirmed that the port is open and that the docker containers running perfectly matches what the unedited (and working) test network scripts create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find the issue until setting `VERBOSE=true` in the script, and it became apparent that the environment variable `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED` was not set to `true` like in the test script. Even though I had set it, I did not do `export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true` which is necessary to make it available when the `peer` command is running.